# Focus on input by using jQuery

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I'm working on a webpage where jquery is loaded and there is an input field on the webpage, which supports auto completion, so after typing several characters, a selection of suggestion box shows itself. By using dev tools' console, i can be able force that suggestion list to be generated and be appeared on demand, by executing following jquery functions (*in browser console*):

```
$('input#PrincipalPolicyHolder_EmploymentOccupationDescription').val("soft");

setTimeout(function() { $('input#PrincipalPolicyHolder_EmploymentOccupationDescription').focus(); }, 5000);

setTimeout(function() { $('input#PrincipalPolicyHolder_EmploymentOccupationDescription').keyup(); }, 6000);
```

The delay is required for me to change the focus to the window from console. These jQuery commands are enough to get `$('#PrincipalPolicyHolder_EmploymentOccupationDescription').is('focus')` true which is required to generate a list of suggestions, as long as i don't click to somewhere else.

However, the same steps don't work in casperjs environment. This is how i execute;

```
casper.then(function () {
    this.evaluate(function () {
        $('input#PrincipalPolicyHolder_EmploymentOccupationDescription').val("soft");
        $('input#PrincipalPolicyHolder_EmploymentOccupationDescription').focus();
        $('input#PrincipalPolicyHolder_EmploymentOccupationDescription').keyup();
    });
});
```

I also tried to use sendKeys with `keepFocus: true`, but never got `is(':focus')` check positive. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Edit:
I narrowed down the problem to work on a very simple webpage, Here is the code snippet that captures the issue:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    loglevel: "debug"
});

casper.start('http://jsfiddle.net/vhermL99/embedded/result/');

casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
    this.echo('remote message caught: ' + msg);
});

casper.withFrame(0, function () {
    casper.thenEvaluate( function () {
    var input = $('#input1');
    input.val("value set by jquery");
    input.focus();
    console.log("is input focussed: " + input.is(':focus'));
    });
    casper.then(function () {
    this.capture('before-sendkey.png');
    });
    casper.then(function () {
    casper.sendKeys('#input1', 'value set by sendKeys', {'reset': true, 'keepFocus': true});
    });
    casper.thenEvaluate(function () {
    console.log("is input focussed: " + $('#input1').is(':focus'));
    });
    casper.then(function () {
    this.capture('before-sendkey.png');
    });

});

casper.run();
```

The expectation is having `.is(':focus')` true in one of two methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same thing in CasperJS that you have done in the browser console too. You only need to be aware that you break out of the control flow of CasperJS when you start asynchronous processes in the page context. So you need to wait for results in the casper context, because now you have effectively two control flows.

```
casper.thenEvaluate(function () {
    $('input#PrincipalPolicyHolder_EmploymentOccupationDescription').val("soft");

    setTimeout(function() { 
        $('input#PrincipalPolicyHolder_EmploymentOccupationDescription').focus(); 
    }, 5000);

    setTimeout(function() { 
        $('input#PrincipalPolicyHolder_EmploymentOccupationDescription').keyup(); 
    }, 6000);
});
casper.wait(10000, function(){
    // waited 10 seconds, so do something with the autocomplete result
});
```

You can also try it with the native PhantomJS [`sendEvent`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/send-event.html) function:

```
casper.then(function () {
    this.evaluate(function(){
        var el = document.querySelector('input#PrincipalPolicyHolder_EmploymentOccupationDescription');
        el.focus();
    });
    this.page.sendEvent('keypress', 'soft');
});
casper.wait(10000, function(){
    // waited 10 seconds, so do something with the autocomplete result
});
```

Comment: I added casperjs.wait but didn't work either. The problem is, even you remove setTimeout() functions (frankly i couldn't understand why you put those in CasperJS context) and execute immediately jquery focus() and the ```is(':focus')``` check, you will see that the focus check is never true.

Comment: Regardless of whether the input is focussed or not, did the autocomplete suggestions open? Also how do you do you check that something happened on the page? Do you take a screenshot or do you only rely on this one `is(':focus')` test?

Comment: The autocomplete does not work because, the autocompleter function checks for ```is(':focus')``` on the element. Autocompleter populates a list and CasperJS function waits for that list. Besides that I take screenshot and it seems element is focused (except the fact that i dont see cursor, though, im not sure if i am supposed to see). Interesting thing is, exactly same jquery instructions work on the console but doesn't work when executed by CasperJS for some reason.

Comment: Please register to the [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error) events. Also, please register to the [`resource.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#resource-error) and [`casper.page.onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html) events. Maybe there are errors.

Comment: Added simplified example in my first message.

Answer (score 0):

this is not a good idea at all to set timeouts.

Considering you are using the latest CasperJS release, it's better to use the waitFor utility method: http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html?highlight=waitfor#waitfor.

Also, you may emulate the behavior to "type" into your text input by using the sendKeys method: http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html?highlight=waitfor#sendkeys.

Regards,

Comment: I've mentioned that sendKeys never worked for me in this case.

Comment: Should work: https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/master/modules/casper.js#L1598.
Did you try to split your process on many ``then`` assertions ? Maybe jQuery is called before casperJS sendKeys call.

Comment: Please see the last part of my first message.